# How to make a method receive two different data types and return only one of them C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've started learning C# by myself this week, and I might have trouble understanding a few concepts so sorry for any difficulty understanding me. 
 I want to create a method which receives int[] and int, but returns only int[]. 
I received two errors.

For the main method:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int'

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Num = new int[5];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Num[i] = NumGen(Num, i);
    }
```

The created method:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

```
  static int[] NumGen(int[] Num, int i)
    {
        Random rndm = new Random();
        Num[i] = rndm.Next(100) + 1;
        return Num[i];

     }
```

I want to understand what I've done wrong and how to avoid this mistake in the future.
Thank you for the answers in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks everyone, your suggestions solved the problem. :)

Comment: It is slightly odd that you assign the value to the array both inside the method and outside - is that intentional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just the return type of `NumGen` - should be `int`:

```
static int NumGen(int[] Num, int i)
{
    Random rndm = new Random();
    Num[i] = rndm.Next(100) + 1;
    return Num[i];
}
```

BUT: your code has a serious bug. `new Random()` like that will produce the same value every time, due to how it is seeded via the clock. A better approach would be:

```
static int NumGen(Random rndm, int[] Num, int i)
{
    Num[i] = rndm.Next(100) + 1;
    return Num[i];
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] Num = new int[5];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Num[i] = NumGen(rand, Num, i);
}
```

Or more cleanly:

```
static int Randomize(Random rndm)
{
    return rndm.Next(100) + 1;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] Num = new int[5];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Num[i] = Randomize(rand);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a method that returns an array of int (`int[] NumGen()`), while assigning its return value to an int (`Num[i] = NumGen()`) *and* only returning a single int from it (`return Num[i];`).

If you can explain what this code is expected to do, perhaps we can suggest what this code should look like.

You can probably replace it all with:

```
var random = new Random();
int[] randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
                                .Select(i => random.Next(100) + 1)
                                .ToArray();
```

But that would miss the point of learning about [arrays and their syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Num[i] is an int, not int[]. Because it is an item from the int array and any element in that array is int. So replace first line:

```
static int NumGen(int[] Num, int i)
    {
        Random rndm = new Random();
        Num[i] = rndm.Next(100) + 1;
        return Num[i];

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

you want your function to return int (a number) not int[] (an array of numbers)

change to

```
static int NumGen(int[] Num, int i)
```

and it should be ok ;)